# Extending a range of fractions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007, range

I'm trying to fill a range with fractions i.e. 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, 1/9 etc.
When i try to drag the fill handle down it gives me all kinds of odd results. e.g.-1/8, -1/5, -2/7 etc.
Any ideas on how to get Excel to just continue the series?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make it into three columns.

Make a nominator column, and a denominator column.  Then make a column with the formula.

```
1  3  =1/3
1  4  =1/4
1  5  =1/5
1  6  =1/6
1  7  =1/7
```

If it's not a regular interval it excel won't be able to intuit the pattern.

Comment: I must be particlarly thick today.
1 in a1 3 in b1 and what exactly in c1?

Comment: @Auto in C1: =A1/B1

Comment: +1 to dtang.  Format c1 as a fraction in "format cells" (CTRL+1) and it'll work.  I tested it.

Comment: @Auto - Happy to help.  If it worked for you, please accept the answer.